# Wrong results multiplying two 32 bit numbers in C

Tags: c, matrix, arm, fixed-point, cortex-m

I am trying two multiply to matrices in C and I cant understand why I get these results...

I want to do : **Btranspose * B**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>                        
#include <math.h>     

#define LOW_WORD(x)  (((x) << 16) >> 16) 
#define HIGH_WORD(x) ((x) >> 16)
#define ABS(x) (((x) >= 0) ? (x) : -(x))
#define SIGN(x) (((x) >= 0) ? 1 : -1)

#define UNSIGNED_MULT(a, b) \
    (((LOW_WORD(a)  * LOW_WORD(b))  <<  0) + \
     (((int64_t)((LOW_WORD((a)) * HIGH_WORD((b))) + (HIGH_WORD((a)) * LOW_WORD((b))))) << 16) + \
     ((int64_t)(HIGH_WORD((a)) * HIGH_WORD((b))) << 32))

#define MULT(a, b)  (UNSIGNED_MULT(ABS((a)), ABS((b))) * SIGN((a)) * SIGN((b)))


int main()
{
    int c,d,k;
    int64_t multmatrix[3][3];
    int64_t sum64 = 0;
    int32_t Btranspose[3][3] = {{15643, 24466, 58751},
                               {54056, 26823, -25563},
                               {-33591, 54561, -13777}};
    int32_t B[3][3] = {{15643, 54056, -33591},
                      {24466, 26823, 54561},
                      {58751, -25563, -13777}};

    for ( c = 0 ; c < 3 ; c++ ){
        for ( d = 0 ; d < 3 ; d++ ){
            for ( k = 0 ; k < 3 ; k++ ){
                sum64 = sum64 + MULT(Btranspose[c][k], B[k][d]);
                printf("\n the MULT for k = %d is: %ld \n", k, MULT(Btranspose[c][k], B[k][d]));
                printf("\n the sum for k = %d is: %ld \n", k, sum64);
            }
            multmatrix[c][d] = sum64;
            sum64 = 0;
        }
    }       

    printf("\n\n multmatrix \n");
    for( c = 0 ; c < 3; c++ ){
        printf("\n");
        for( d = 0 ; d < 3 ; d++ ){
            printf(" %ld  ", multmatrix[c][d]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output is below put that is wrong and I notice that the mistake is when is multiplying the 3rd element (58751 * 58751) for k=2.
I think is not overflowing because 58751^2 needs 32bits.

```
the MULT for k = 0 is: 244703449

the sum for k = 0 is: 244703449

the MULT for k = 1 is: 598585156

the sum for k = 1 is: 843288605

the MULT for k = 2 is: 46036225   // this is WRONG!!!

the sum for k = 2 is: 889324830
.
.
.
.
the MULT for k = 2 is: 189805729

the sum for k = 2 is: 1330739379


multmatrix

889324830   650114833   324678230
650114833   1504730698   -308929574
324678230   -308929574   1330739379
```

Correct result should be

```
   multmatrix - correct

   4.2950e+09  -2.2870e+03   1.2886e+04
  -2.2870e+03   4.2950e+09  -1.2394e+05
   1.2886e+04  -1.2394e+05   4.2951e+09
```

Why is the multiplication of the matrix wrong??
What should I change the above code so that the multiplication of two matrices will be overflow-proof??

(I am trying write a program that multiplies two 32 bits numbers to be imported on a system that has only 32 bit registers)

---

So according to the **answer below** this actually **works**.

```
#define LOW_WORD(x)  ((uint32_t)(x) & 0xffff)
#define HIGH_WORD(x) ((uint32_t)(x) >> 16)
#define ABS(x) (((x) >= 0) ? (x) : -(x))
#define SIGN(x) (((x) >= 0) ? 1 : -1)

#define UNSIGNED_MULT(a, b) \
    (((LOW_WORD(a)  * LOW_WORD(b))  <<  0) + \
     ((int64_t)(LOW_WORD(a) * HIGH_WORD(b) + HIGH_WORD(a) * LOW_WORD(b)) << 16) + \
     ((int64_t)(HIGH_WORD((a)) * HIGH_WORD((b))) << 32))

#define MULT(a, b)  (UNSIGNED_MULT(ABS((a)), ABS((b))) * SIGN((a)) * SIGN((b)))
```

Thank you for helping me understand some things! I'll try turning the whole thing to functions and posting it back.

Comment: I'm too lazy to parse it properly but the high x low << 16 part generates a 48-bit result and ought to be cast to 64-bits.

Comment: Your shift macros cause undefined behaviour. A good start would be to change  `LOW_WORD` to `#define LOW_WORD(x)  ((x) % 0x10000u)` although there are other problems too

Comment: Oh, and while I can sympathize with not trusting certain compilers not to inline properly then at least try to unwind the macro mess into straight-line C before attempting to debug it (or at the very least before subjecting us to it)

Comment: Thank you for your time guys :) I am sorry if the question wasnt clearly written. I edited the question providing all the code. I am new to C...
@doynax I tried casting the intermediate steps but the result doesnt change. What do you mean by unwinding the macro; just make it two parts?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I know I cant use `[]` i have edited my question. If now is more readable to you and you could explain what the other problems are or why the proposed `LOW_WORD(x) ((x) % 0x10000u)` is better it would be great

Comment: @Franx `LOW_WORD` and `HI_WORD` only work properly if invoked on a `uint32_t`.  With other types they do the wrong thing and/or cause undefined behaviour. For example left-shifting into the sign bit causes undefined behaviour; and right-shifting negative value probably doesn't achieve what you intend.

Comment: @Franx: I simply meant getting rid of the macros by expanding them, preferably replacing them with functions and/or sub-expressions. This ought to make the code a fair bit clearer and easier to trace through in a debugger. As it stands you have to mentally expand the code to work out what is going on in the intermediate types and expressions.

Comment: It's strange to me that LOW_WORD and HIGH_WORD implies a implementation of 16x16=31 while the question clearly states a problem of 32x32=63.

Comment: How have you tested the MULT macro in isolation?  Have you ensured it works correctly for representative values over the entire range of 32-bit input values?  Why do you think you need to worry about multiplying to 32-bit values when your machine supports `int64_t`?  All you have to do is ensure that at least one of the two operands of the multiplication is an `int64_t` and the compiler will do it for you. Compilers can do the job more efficiently than you can, regardless of whether the target machine has 64-bit registers. You're letting the compiler add 64-bit values; let it multiply too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
(((x) << 16) >> 16)
```

doesn't produce unsigned 16-bit number, as you might expect. The type of this expression is the same as the type of `x`, which is `int32_t` (signed integer). Indeed, if using any sensible (two's complement) C implementation, for `x=58751`:

```
x                   = 00000000000000001110010101111111
(x) << 16           = 11100101011111110000000000000000 (negative number)
(((x) << 16) >> 16) = 11111111111111111110010101111111 (negative number)
```

To extract the low 16 bits properly, use unsigned arithmetic:

```
((uint32_t)(x) & 0xffff)
```

or (preserving your style)

```
((uint32_t)(x) << 16 >> 16)
```

To get the high word, you have to use unsigned arithmetic too:

```
((uint32_t)(x) >> 16)
```

Also, the compiler might need help determining the range of this expression (to do optimizations):

```
(uint16_t)((uint32_t)(x) & 0xffff)
```

Some (all?) compilers are smart enough to do that by themselves though.

---

Also, as noted by doynax, the product of low word and high word is a 32-bit number (or 31-bit, but it doesn't matter). To shift it left by 16 bits, you have to cast it to a 64-bit type, just like you do it with the high words:

```
((int64_t)(LOW_WORD(a) * HIGH_WORD(b) + HIGH_WORD(a) * LOW_WORD(b)) << 16)
```

Comment: Why not just cast to int16_t?

Comment: @user3528438 Yeah that would be the best thing to do. But maybe not portable in the language-lawyer sense?